# When to create a new table?

Tags: sql, database, entity-framework, database-design, data-structures

I have an application with employees and their work contracts.
Each work contract has a Vacation. We keep track of how many days the company owes the employee ("VacationOwe") and how many he has taken ("VacationTaken").

Should I make this "VacationOwe" and "VacationTaken" a property of the Contract, or should I create a class (table) called Vacaction with the properties "VacationOwe", "VacationTaken" and "ContractId" and join the two tables?

What are the advantange of both methods?
Is there any rule when you should create a new class or table or keep the data in one.

Comment: Exactly what @Stefan said, you will take a performance hit if you make another table. The other reason besides the ones he listed, that you'd want to have a separate table is if you wanted to be able to track changes, like they took 2 days starting from jan 17th, and then aggregate the data to get the actual taken and actual owed.

Comment: You are likely to want to store each vacation day taken as a spearate record in a related table. This is because sooner or later someone is going to dispute the totals. You need for legal reasons the exact dates of days off.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the two properties are truly only related to an employee, there's no benefit of creating a separate table. Performance will be worse and you'll constantly have to join on those tables.

For this specific example, it seems like the vacation days may also be linked to a year. If that's the case, a separate table would make sense so you can track vacation days taken/owed by employee and year.

Answer (score 1):

> should I make this "VacationOwe" and "VacationTaken" a propertie o the employee

Most probably...No. Because this defeats normalization. Also, it does not provide information about when the vacations were taken (in case you care about that). In addition to that, you have to do this calculation for every employee, every year.

> Use a class (table) Call Vacaction with properties "VacationOwe" and "VacationTaken" and "EmployeeId" and cross the two tables?

It is not good to have a singleton class in this case. In general you should avoid singletons in most cases.

So what to do? Well, if you system does not care about vacation details, you could go with the first solution. Maybe you want to consider option (A) below or If you would like to have a more generic approach you could do something similar to option (B). It all depends on your detailed requirements.

[image]

Comment: I agree that you need to just keep mixing in a little more information.  If you really aren't sure, then that is itself a reason for more normalization - one set of database design "rules". You have more options later if you are more normalized.  This answer by @EmmadKareem suggests one example... what if you stored VacationDays in your [Employee] table, but that employee has a new contract with new/different vacation?  Do you want to document the change?

Comment: If you want to learn more about these rules called "normalization", here is an SO post with several links: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4820015/how-do-you-teach-database-normalization

Comment: @Mike M, thanks for your comment. The case you mentioned is valid in some businesses and I am quite pro collecting detailed requirements before modeling. Regarding your point, the total number of vacations could be stored in the junction table in (B).

Comment: Indeed, indeed.  Just to clarify, I was certainly writing for the OP.  I'm sure you already understand, @emmadkareem.  That's why I commented in your answer (rather than writing a new answer).